# Why have I errors when installing from Luarocks?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am the developer of this small library: https://github.com/martin-damien/babel and I have a problem with Luarocks releases.

## From source

When I install from source with Luarocks I have no problem:

```
$ luarocks make --local rockspecs/babel-1.2-2.rockspec
```

## From internet

But when deployed (using: tag `master`, add new rockspec release and publish to Luarocks), I can't install using

```
$ luarocks install --local babel
```

Because I encounter the following error:

> Installing https://luarocks.org/babel-1.2-2.src.rock...
>   Using https://luarocks.org/babel-1.2-2.src.rock... switching to 'build' > mode
>   stat: malsukcesis eltrovi statinformon pri «locales/zh-HK.lua»: No such > file or directory
>
> Error: Build error: Failed installing locales/zh-HK.lua in /home/damien/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks/babel/1.2-2/lua/locales/zh-HK.lua: locales/zh-HK.lua: No such file or directory

As you can see in https://github.com/martin-damien/babel/issues/14 the error occure on different files (but until now, only with locale files, not with the `babel.lua` file).

I have no idea why it randomly crash like this, so if someone know why or have an idea from where it could come from...

Thanks in advance,

Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the files in the `build.modules` table is (from [the docs](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Rockspec-format#builtin) on the rockspec format):

> relative to **source.dir**

Where `source.dir` is

> source.dir (string) - the name of the directory created when the source archive is unpacked. Can be omitted if it can be inferred from the source.file field. Example: "luasocket-2.0.1"

and `source.file` is

> source.file (string) - the filename of the source archive. Can be omitted if it can be inferred from the source.url field. Example: "luasocket-2.0.1.tar.gz"

You don't specify `source.dir` or `source.file` in [your rockspec](https://github.com/martin-damien/babel/blob/master/rockspecs/babel-1.2-2.rockspec) but you do set `source.url` (because you have to).

So you have `source.url` = `https://github.com/martin-damien/babel/archive/v1.2-2.zip` which (presumably) ends up with `source.file` = `v1.2-2.zip` and then `source.dir` = `v1.2-2` but your zip file extracts into a `babel-1.2` so `luarocks` can't find your source files. (The screenshot in the linked issue seems to indicate that `luarocks` uses `source.file` = `v1.2.zip` and the archive extracts to `babel-1.2` but I'm not sure how that's possible.)

Add `dir = "babel-1.2"` to your rockspec's `source` table an I expect it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. For your information, the screenshot was an older version of babel (1.2) will the messages where from 1.2-2. That was the reason why.

Comment: Ah, that would do it.